# Diablo 2 installer in WINE hangs on EULA (EULA blank and cannot click on Agree)

Tags: wine, games

I am trying to install Diablo 2 inside WINE on Ubuntu using the Downloader from battle.net

It works fine at first but gets stuck on the EULA: The EULA window is blank and I cannot click on "Agree".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On further research, it turns out that WINE needs *Wine Gecko* to display HTML, and for some reason this is not shipped by default.

Go here to download the latest Wine Gecko (32 bit):
https://wiki.winehq.org/Gecko

Install it like this:

```
wine msiexec /i wine_gecko-2.47-x86.msi
```

Afterwards the installer will show the EULA and allow to proceed.

Comment: Also note that if you run `winecfg` it will prompt you to install various things like Gecko HTML rendering.

Comment: @Kristopher Ives I was hoping that was true.  It was not my experience.  Can you tell me an easy way to get Gecko?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the Lutris tool which automates downloading the correct Wine version and tools for games. For example, here is their tool and [script for installing Diablo II: Lord of Destruction](https://lutris.net/games/diablo-ii-lord-of-destruction/).

Also make sure you are using the wine install command from [winehq.org](https://winehq.org) since the version in the Ubuntu repositories is quite old and it's not clear if you're getting the 64-bit or 32-bit version. My advice is remove all wine packages, then run these install commands from the winehq.org site:

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

Comment: I have tried Lutris but it has not worked well for me. My wine version is 3.0.2, so should be new enough.